# Filling missing values for Embedded List in Python3

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning, feature-engineering, dataframe, python-3.x

I searched for a similar question but I didn't come across. And I'm new in this area, I hope I explained my question well enough.

I have a dataset consist of text data. I store them in a list and every row of a list consists of a string value. But every row length is not equal. I want them to be equal, so I can use them in a self-attention model.

**The sample of my dataset**

```
In [8]: myList
Out[8]: 
[
['the first line of my dataset'], 
['the second line'],
['the 3rd'],
['the 4th'],
['the 5th'],
['the 6th'],
['the 7th'],
]
```

So as you can see the first one is longer than the rest of them. I want to fill with a certain value like `#` to equalize the word count.

**The sample output I'd like to do**

```
In [8]: myList
Out[8]: 
[
['the first line of my dataset'], 
['the second line # # #'],
['the 3rd # # # #'],
['the 4th # # # #'],
['the 5th # # # #'],
['the 6th # # # #'],
['the 7th # # # #']
]
```

If this would be a dataframe I could use `fillna()` function of **Pandas library**. I tried to apply this:

`train_X = pd.Series(train_X).fillna("#").values`

but since it is an embedded list(I guess) it didn't work. Is there a better way to do that?

Any recommendation is appreciated.

Comment: you can use the `pad_sequences` function from keras, but you'll have to tokenize your sentences first.

Comment: Thank you I'll check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the suggestion, @bkshi gave to me I come up with a solution here below:

Also since `texts_to_sequences()` function convert my list to sequences starting from 1, I could use `pad_sequence()` and use *0* instead of a *string* value.

This solution satisfies my requirements so I used a number as padding instead of a string value.

```py
import pandas as pd
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

my_list = [['the first line'],
       ['the 2nd line'],
       ['the 3r line'],
       ['the 4th line'],
       ['the 5th line'],
       ['the'],
       ['the 5th line, this is']]
max_features = 10 #how many unique words you're using

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_features)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(my_list)
my_list = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(my_list)
my_list = pad_sequences(train_X, maxlen=None, dtype='int32', padding='post', truncating='post', value=0.0)
```